# Spectral mixture analysis from GeoTIFF in ENVI

Tags: geotiff-tiff, envi

I have a single GeoTIFF created from some NGB aerial photography that has been stitched in Agisoft Photoscan to create a single image of an area of heath.

I would like to perform spectral mixture analysis on the GeoTIFF but am lost as to where to start. I have sample photographs for end member selection. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spectral mixture analysis / sub pixel analysis is designed for hyperspectral data, not a 3-band aerial photograph. However, you can try it and see if the output is useful. A tutorial can be found in [this pdf](http://geology.isu.edu/dml/ENVI_Tutorials/Adv_Hyperspectral_Analysis.pdf) and in [this ppt/pdf](http://www.sfpt.fr/hyperspectral/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cours_Licciardi.pdf). You will have to skip a significant number of the steps, as you don't have the same amount of information in your dataset. In essence, you can skip the preprocessing steps and go directly to assigning your endmembers based on the geolocation of your photos. Main issue that you'll most likely run into is that you'll want more classes than your 3-band data can actually provide.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. This looks useful. Is there another image analysis technique that might be better for classifying vegitation using RGB/NGB aerial imagery?

Comment: @Willburt, when limited by spectral information, you can start looking at spatial information. You can do this by looking into object based classification / image segmentation. The entry barrier is rather high for this, and it may require a fair amount of effort to get into. Personally, I use eCognition for this type of work, but Orfeo Toolbox (as part of QGis / OSGeo4W) should also be able to do it.

Comment: Youre right Mikkel. SMA wasn't very useful however your info guided me towards OBIA. So I'm looking at a combination of spatial and spectral classification now. Thanks :)